# How do I count a value over time thats unique in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

So the scenario is I have an index that contains the values of what im trying to achieve listed below.

```
{"organisation":"TestOrg","deployment_name":"testDeployment","timestamp":1    499724427000,"running_instances":2}
```

Thats how they are stored in elastic. Deployment name could be anything and what im trying to do is calculate the running instances for any deployment.

This is what ive tried so far.

My Idea was that I would do a date histogram with terms and cardinality the value i wanted kinda like below.

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "vms_over_time" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
            "field" : "timestamp",
            "interval" : "2h"
        },
    "aggs": {
        "termsagg" : {
            "termf":{ "field" : "deployment_name"}
        },
        "cardcheck":{
            "cardinality" : {
                "cardf" : { "field":"running_instances"} 
            }
            }
         }

      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your requirement right. With the cardinality agg you are counting the number of distinct elements in `running_instances`, so if you have `1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4` the response will be `4`.

Is it possible that you just want to use a `sum` aggregation to count the number of running instances? Even though this would not work with your current data model. Maybe a min/max and average value might help?

Comment: I'm trying to work out a way to check the documents instances and add together. The timestamps of different deployments.  E.g. dep1 has two instances, dep4 has 3 instances at 5pm. Total amount is 5. Is this possible or am I interpreting it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was as dumb as me basically to count the field I needed and work out the total amount. I needed to use a Date Histogram which had a sub aggregation of Terms which proceeded to have a sub aggregation of sum on the running_instances.

The issue I ran into was terms as the field I wanted to use was text so I made a keyword.